# Information on ice maker water inlet for LG LFXS26973S refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, water-pressure, ice-maker

My LG refrigerator after working fine for some time has started dripping water from the in-door ice maker.

When I run a cycle, I can see that the water is gushing into the icemaker, where it launches up the channel ramp onto the side of the icemaker and then drips past the ice tray.  I can't tell if the water is just coming in at too high a pressure and getting in the wrong place, or if the water is going to the right place, but shouldn't be leaking past the side of the tray.

The ice maker and the water channel all seem to be intact.  The water injector is part of the door, not part of the ice maker.  I can't find if there's a part number for it, or if there's supposed to be a nozzle or diffuser on the injector (maybe that has recently fallen off mine).

There doesn't seem to be a blockage on the water injector.  I took a toothpick and probed inside and didn't feel anything odd.  It didn't seem to have hard water deposits blocking or similar, but the area that can be probed is pretty small.

Is there a method to either redirect the water or lower the pressure that is coming into the ice maker?

Comment: ...and it's tales like this (as well as more efficient use of limited freezer space) that make me continue to be happy with not having bought a fridge with an ice maker or water disenser (despite which they keep trying to get me to buy replacement water filters...)